# Maximum Distance to the Center and Foci for a Point Inside an Ellipse

Tags: geometry

Given an ellipse with foci $f_1$ and $f_2$, major axis $M$, minor axis $m$ and center $c$ how could I find the maximum distance that a point inside the ellipse can be to $f_1$, $f_2$ or $c$ such that the distance to any of them would be smaller than the distance to the other reference points?

In other words, which is the maximum distance $dist_{max}(p_1,f_1)$ such that $p_1$ is inside the ellipse and $(dist(p_1,f_1) < dist(p_1,f_2)) \wedge (dist(p_1,f_1) < dist(p_1,c))$ ?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Such inequalities just mean that $p_1$ has to lie on the left of the perpendicular bisector of $f_1 f_2$ and on the left of the perpendicular bisector of $f_1 c$. So the first inequality is redundant.

Comment: So using that hint, can you see what the maximum distance is?

Comment: To be honest, I still have no idea how to obtain the maximum distance! Thanks for the comments guys!

Comment: Actually, I'm still trying to figure out this question. From the comment, if I consider a perpendicular bisector of $f_1c$ the line segment would be on the quarter of the eccentricity of the ellipse. So, the is it right to say that the maximum distance is a quarter of the eccentricity $e$ of the ellipse?

For the center it will be ok for most cases, but isn't it possible for the semi-minor axis to be greater than half the eccentricity (i.e., m/2 > e/4)? Or it will never happen?

Comment: In addition, the same for the foci, can't the difference between the semi-major axis and half of the eccentricity be greater than half of the eccentricity (i.e., (M/2-e/4)>e/4)?